# Bootstrap responsive sidebar logo rendering on small devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I try to implement a responsive Sidebar menu with Bootstrap3 but I have problems to render properly for small devices

The Markup looks like

```
    <div id="sidebar" class="col-md-3 "> 
//if desktop than display this logo 
         <a class="logo_big" href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/" title="<?php bloginfo('name') ?>" rel="homepage">
               <img  class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/logo.jpg">
         </a>
        <div class="sidebar-nav">
          <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
                <span class="visible-sm navbar-brand">
                    //if mobile or tablet us this logo
                    <a class="block-title navbar-brand" href="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/" title="<?php bloginfo('name') ?>" rel="homepage">
                        <img  class="img-responsive logo" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/library/images/logo.jpg">
                    </a>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse">

                <?php bones_main_nav(); ?> 

            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
          </div>
        </div>


        <div id="right_sidebar_widgets">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar1'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here I have a custom css to render the logo, but doesn't seems to show the desired

```
.logo{
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {


    a.logo_big{
        display: none;
    }

    .logo{
        max-width: 145px;
        position: relative;
        right: 25px;
        bottom: 25px;
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: can you maybe add a screenshot or a diagram?

Comment: thanks for feedback I make a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand that `max-width: 145px;` will not work unless `width` is specified, [per MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)

> The max-width CSS property is used to set the maximum width of a given
>   element. It prevents the used value of the width property from
>   becoming larger than the value specified for max-width.

You also need to set the `display` property of the logo in order for it to show.

Try:

```
.logo{
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {


    a.logo_big{
        display: none;
    }

    .logo{
        width: 145px;
        position: relative;
        display:inline-block; /* <--- set to display */
        right: 25px;
        bottom: 25px;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm you have .logo {display: none;} and .logo_big {display: none;} 
Try with display: inline;